# BigQuery BigLake External Table Data Delay

Tags: google-bigquery

Streaming big data is coming into my Cloud Storage. I created a BigLake External Table in BigQuery, then I created a materialized view to do some transformations and connected it to looker studio(Datastudio).
Then I realized that my dashboard is not working as streaming. The data in it is updated every 15-20 minutes or so.

I did a few things with the metadata cache but I couldn't solve the problem.
Does anyone have any ideas?